# Python : Transfrom a dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, dataframe

How can i transfrom my below dataframe to the json output ?
reference,referenceParent,level,description,storeChain,descriptions

The json output :

```
data = '[ { "hierarchies": [ ' 
       '{' 
       ' "reference": "Sephsub",' 
       ' "referenceParent": "SephC",' 
       ' "level": 2,' 
       ' "description": "sous_sc1",' 
       ' "storeChain": "S_FR",' 
       ' "descriptions": ""' 
       ' }]'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Python pandas has to_json method. You can use like `data = df.to_json(orient="records")`
Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to loop through the keys and values and make a dictionary and then just use

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```